# Find the probability of a device failure

Tags: probability

A device ceases to work if at least $5$ first type of light bulbs burn out or at least $2$ second type light bulbs burn out. Find the probability of the device ceasing to work, knowing that $5$ bulbs burned out (but not which type). The probability of the first type of light bulbs to burn out is $0.7$ and the probability of the second type of light bulbs to burn out is $0.3$

Comment: You should edit your question to include what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: The point is that I'm stuck exactly at the start, because of it having 2 separate failure factors. I tried getting the probability of 5 failing in first type bulbs, adding to it 3 first type fail & 2 second type fails but that isn't right.

Comment: Do you know about the binomial distribution? One way to think about the problem is call each bulb failure a *sucess* if it is a type 1 bulb failure. Then the two failure modes can be thought of in terms of the number of successes out of $5$ independent trials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call a bulb failure a **sucess** if it is a type one bulb failure. Then, the probability of success is $0.7$. Let $N$ be the number of successes, then noting that we have $5$ trials, it is clear that $N$ is distributed binomially, i.e., $\text{Bin}(5,0.7)$.

Now, there are two ways for the device to fail. Either $N=5$ meaning all the bulbs were type 1, or $N\leq 3$ meaning at least 2 of the failures were from type 2 bulbs. Since we know how $N$ is distributed, we can compute this directly.

In particular, the probability of getting exactly $k$ sucesses is $$P(N=k)={{5}\choose{k}} 0.7^k(1-0.7)^{5-k}.$$

Comment: As a matter of fact, about 15 minutes ago I tried going the binomial way as well and had success! Thank you David, this is the correct answer.